# How to use TLS with non RTOS

Tags: ssl, stm32, tls1.2, lwip

I want to use TLS with stm32f4 for the communication safe for the modbus-tcp, but I dont want to use RTOS, how can I do that ? Is that possible? I am using lwip raw api, lwip documentation says it is possible but what is the method ?

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question.

Comment: Hi, Unfortunately, This question is a little bit too vague, it asks very generally for what would constitute a tutorial instead of asking a specific question. Therefore it is not suitable for stackoverflow as Stackoverflow is not a tutorial provider or a free code writing service. Goodluck :)

Comment: I want to use TLS with non-RTOS but, cubemx does no generate mbedtls lwip without freertos